# What is the appropriate way to load WinForms settings to GUI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, application-settings

I am building an application, which has a form where the user can configure all his settings. When the application is loaded, the previously configured settings should reflect to the GUI (The UI should be consistent to the saved settings).

What I am currently doing is creating the settings on the project properties and I have a `LoadSettings()` method, which gets the values and outputs them to each component on the UI.

The thing is that this is getting VERY messy, and I don't like it at all.

So, that got me wondering, what are the correct approaches to achieve what I want, but yet getting high quality code? Any patterns for that?

```
private void LoadConfigs()
        {
            checkBoxStartOnStartup.Checked = ExistKeyValue(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", "Wallbase Downloader");
            checkBoxCheckWallbaseOnline.Checked = Settings.Default.CheckWallbaseOnlineStartup;

            comboBoxResolution.SelectedIndex = comboBoxResolution.FindStringExact(Settings.Default.Resolution == string.Empty 
                ? GetScreenResolution() 
                : Settings.Default.Resolution);

            comboBoxCondition.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.ConditionIndex;

            textBoxWallpaperFolders.Text = Settings.Default.WallpaperFolder;

            numericChangeInterval.Text = Convert.ToString(Settings.Default.ChangeIntervalValue);
            comboBoxChangeInterval.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.ChangeIntervalIndex;

            numericCheckInterval.Text = Convert.ToString(Settings.Default.CheckIntervalValue);
            comboBoxCheckInterval.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.CheckIntervalIndex;

            numericWallpapersToLookFor.Text = Settings.Default.WallpapersToLookFor.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: In your current solution, Are you using the Form's ApplicationSettings ?

Comment: Probably not since that isn't "messy".

Comment: They are, take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Well, WinForms are not the cleanest framework around...

What you could do is to load all settings when your application starts up and store them in some storage that is available to all forms, e.g. in a static property in a helper settings class.

You can then access that static property from each form when it loads and make all necessary changes to the form based on the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use English strings for key to make your code really readable. Then [serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it to file on exit and [deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it back when application loads. Save the serialized file to some [common location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that you do not lose it.

Comment: It would be as messy as the current setup, if not worse. I would still need to get each value and load them to each component. Maybe there is someway to make each component save and load it's setting?

Comment: I believe there is no lazy way out to do this. First of all, the config data and UI should be separate, that is why you have to manually assign them back into the UI control. You could write an interface that automatically format values from the hashtable to your UI control using some custom rule e.g. type checking and custom format rules; Loop Form.Controls collection and assign in order etc.; or you can write getter/setter for your form class and make the whole form serializable. Regardless, that is still a lot of work.